Wordpress - All block assets are being enqueued on every page, causing a performance issue by loading unnecessary scripts and styles
I've created gutenberg blocks using wp-scripts wordpress library. Website is getting large, and every blocks assets, like css, is enqueued on every page. I'm afraid if the website keeps growing that it's going to be a performance issue.
This is my code for registering blocks inside my custom plugin:
class Custom_Theme_Functions {
    function __construct() {
        add_filter('styles_inline_size_limit', '__return_zero');
        add_action('init', [$this, 'register_blocks']);
    }

    function register_blocks() {
        $dirUrl =  __DIR__ . '/build/';
        $originalBlocks = [
            'homepage-hero',
            'categories-scroll',
            'partitioners-list',
            'google-reviews',
            'locations-display',
            'blog-list'
        ];

        foreach ($originalBlocks as $block) {
            register_block_type($dirUrl . $block . '/block.json');
        }
    }
}

